# Building SonarQube with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-4.5

I tried to build a SonarQube job with Jenkins and even it worked at the beginning, now it fails with the following exception.

My Jenkins and SonarQube instance work on a Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise.

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)  
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot analyse the file 'D:\Appl\CI\Jenkins\workspace\AWSE1Modules\A4_VolSurfHelper.py', details: 'org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pylint": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified'
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintSensor.analyse(PylintSensor.java:91)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more  
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pylint": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:98)
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintArguments.pylintVersion(PylintArguments.java:47)
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintArguments.<init>(PylintArguments.java:39)
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintIssuesAnalyzer.<init>(PylintIssuesAnalyzer.java:46)
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintSensor.analyzeFile(PylintSensor.java:102)
at org.sonar.plugins.python.pylint.PylintSensor.analyse(PylintSensor.java:81)
... 34 more 
       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pylint": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:68)
... 39 more        Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 41 more   
 ERROR:       
 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.   
 Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build a    failure 

      Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have [enabled pylint](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython) based rules, and will [need to install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) it. See the 4th (optional) step in the first link, which mentions this.

Comment: I have already installed pylint on that server, but it seems that sonarqube can't find the exe. Where do I define that?

Comment: Is it found on your Path?

Comment: Now it works, but it takes almost 2 hours, whereas without pylint it took 5 min.